# Ionic 4 Android APK crashes when opening inAppBrowser '_self'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I've built an Ionic 4 app which uses the inAppBrowser component to open an external website at some point of the app flow.

The app is working great but when testing it with real Android phone crashes and the app closes.
Browser, iOS, emulators... all working fine. Only real Android devices crashing when the `this.browser.create(url, '_self')` is called.

I've tested all kind of things. Like putting the code in different modules and different parts of the app workflow.
Also tried to grep the java output from the device, but it's not returning any error message at all.

This is my last try, a very simple approach. But its also crashing:

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      const browser = this.iab.create('https://example.com/', '_self');

      browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
        // this.splashScreen.hide();
      });
    });
  }
```

I have the module imported correctly and also the `<allow-navigation>` tag at the config file.

Comment: i have this problem too, find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

its issue of cordova webview check it is installed and working

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

or pass parameter `_blank` insted of `_self`

Comment: As far as I know, the `_blank` is going to open the inAppBrowser but I want to open the webview with `_self` as I have the URL whitelisted in the config file.

The webview and inappbrowser plugins are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found app crashing two times when...
1) If you pass null or undefined url to In App Browser and target was _self so it could not find and app has been crash

you need to pass **_system**

**OR**

2) You have to specify the options the app will not crash

like this let browser = this.inApp.create(url,'_self','location= no,hardwareback=no,clearsessioncache=yes'); it works